# Latex multiline bracket in a Matlab annotation

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I'm looking to annotate a figure made with Matlab with some bracket that would wrap around 3 lines. An example is given in the figure linked:

[image]

I have succeeded in adding a second legend. But I'm wondering how I could do this really cleanly. I try doing something like this

```
str = '$S_n =$ $\left\{ \begin{tabular}{c} 0.5 MeV \\ 50 keV \\ 5 MeV \end{tabular}\right.$';
annotation('textbox',[0.325,0.175,0.1,0.1],'String',str,'Interpreter','latex','FitBoxToText','on','Linestyle','none')
```

but this gives a result like this one:

[image]

The biggest problems are

- I have to tweek the position of the annotation... But this is not such a big deal. I can spend some time and position it quite well.
- The bracket is too large... And I have no solution for this. How could I do this?

The questions are:

1. Could the bracket be shrunk?
2. If not, could this be done in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the bracket looks good, worrying about the exact size is a bit of a distraction.

However, another option is **adding a title to the legend**.
This would allow you to denote the units/parameter each legend is referring to, without cluttering each line of the legend.  Sadly this is not a native MATLAB functionality, but we can force it.  Exact implementation varies with matlab version.

PRE 2014 CODE

```
function zz_LegendTitle(LegendHandle , TitleText, Fontsize)
% Workaround to Matlab 2014 thinking that legends don't need titles.
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
if ~exist('Fontsize','var'); Fontsize = 10; end 
if ~exist('TitleText','var'); TitleText = 'example text'; end 


% Create an invisible axes at the same position as the legend
hLegendAxes = axes('Parent',LegendHandle.Parent, 'Units',LegendHandle.Units, 'Position',LegendHandle.Position, ...
                   'XTick',[] ,'YTick',[], 'Color','none', 'YColor','none', 'XColor','none', 'HandleVisibility','off', 'HitTest','off');

% Add the axes title (will appear directly above the legend box)
hTitle = title(hLegendAxes, TitleText,...
                'interpreter','latex',...
                'FontWeight','normal',...
                'FontSize',Fontsize);  % Default is bold-11, which is too large

% Link between some property values of the legend and the new axes
hLinks = linkprop([LegendHandle,hLegendAxes], {'Units', 'Position', 'Visible'});
% persist hLinks, otherwise they will stop working when they go out of scope
setappdata(hLegendAxes, 'listeners', hLinks);

% Add destruction event listener (no need to persist here - this is done by addlistener)
addlistener(LegendHandle, 'ObjectBeingDestroyed', @(h,e)delete(hLegendAxes));
```

[image: Legend Title Example]

POST 2014 CODE

```
    hLegend = legend(LegTxt,...
        'interpreter','latex','FontSize',LegFontSize,...
        'location','eastoutside');
    %resize to fix the legend-enforced size change
    set(ax(1),'Units',units,'position',IcePosVec);

%Attach a title to legend (here be dragons. Matlab 2015+ workaround)
     hlt = text('some text',...
    'Parent', hLegend.DecorationContainer, ...
    'String', 'Title', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
    'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', ...
    'Position', [0.5, 1.05, 0], ...
    'Units', 'normalized');
```

PS. Credit where credit is due, I wrote these bits of code about a year ago by stealing shamelessly from the excellent [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-legend-title) website.